# Understanding and Fixing Image Encryption Using Henon Map Resulting in Original Image, Not Encrypted Image

Tags: map, cryptography

I'm reaching out to this community in my quest to understand and improve an image encryption process using the Henon map. I have created the following Mathematica code to encrypt an image:

```
(*Load your original image*)
originalImage = Import["C:\\Users\\Dell\\Desktop\\363876153_291582770122420_2773842875662130275_n.png"];

(*Define the Hénon map function*)
henonMap[{x_, y_}, a_, b_] := {1 - a x^2 + y, b x};

(*Parameters for the Hénon map*)
a = 1.4;
b = 0.3;

(iterationCount = 10000;
 seed = {0.1, 0.1};
 encryptedImage = 
  Image[ConstantArray[0, ImageDimensions[originalImage]]];
 keyStream = 
  NestList[henonMap[#, a, b] &, seed, iterationCount][[2 ;;]];
 normalizedKeyStream = Rescale[keyStream];
 resizedKeyStream = 
  ImageData[
   ImageResize[Image[normalizedKeyStream], 
    ImageDimensions[originalImage]]];
 alphaChannel = Image[Rescale[resizedKeyStream]];
 encryptedImage = SetAlphaChannel[originalImage, alphaChannel];
 Export["encrypted_henon_image.jpg", encryptedImage];
 encryptedImage)
```

[image]

However, I have encountered issues, and to my surprise, the code seems to produce the original image instead of the encrypted one. I'm looking for guidance and expertise from the Mathematica community to help me identify what might be going wrong and how I can achieve my goal of image encryption using the Henon map.

Your insights, feedback, and suggestions would be highly valuable to me

Comment: You are changing the alpha channel of the original image. That is, you are changing the opacity. However, this is still fundamentally the same image.